# how i can use html code into a message of messages.properties in grails?

Tags: html, grails, properties, gsp, message

MyCode (a line in a gsp of grails)

```
  <h3><g:message code="view.hello"/><span style="color:orange"><g:message code="view.world"/></span><h3></h3>
```

Output

> HelloWorld(in orange World)

But dont like how i put this line of my code. I wish do something like this.

the code i want

> > messages.properties (put inside string+html)
> >
> > > view.helloword= hello>span style="color:orange">World>/span>

But output is:

> > hello>span style="color:orange">World>/span>

Dont look html code. how i can resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Can be done as below:

```
//messages.properties
view.helloworld=Hello <span style="color:orange">World</span>

//gsp
<h3><g:message code="view.helloworld"/></h3>
```

Comment: writing equal the output is Hello <span style="color:orange">World</span> dont do the html code. I believe i wrote in my question, that this was the problem. why is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can add any html to messages  and render message in view quite easy. Answer below works in grails 3.0.1

```
${raw(message(code:"view.hello"))}
```

You can use same approach for any html-like string.